# iMacros using EVAL to remove text

Tags: javascript, java, eval, imacros

I am using EVAL to remove the word [EXTRACT], but it is leaving this []

How can I get rid of it all [EXTRACT] or EXTRACT and []

Here is my code:

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/(EXTRACT|#EANF#)/g, '');")
```

I have also tried

```
    SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/([EXTRACT]|#EANF#)/g, '');")
```

But it never gets rid of []

Help

Answer (score 1):

try this, worked or me

```
    SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\[EXTRACT\\]/g, '');")
```